# Why I can't see all Contacts as a Customer Community Plus User?

Tags: community, customer-community, partner-communities

I've created one community to be used for users with

- Customer Community Plus Licence
- Customer Community Licence
- Partner Community Licence

Now I'm running into sharing problems. Our goal is that all Community Users (regardless if the are Community, Community Plus or Partner) should see **all** contacts.

Our OWD Sharing settings are:

- Account and Contract ==> *Public Read/Write*
- Contact ==> *Controlled by Parent*

**Expected Behavior (as needed for all community users)**

Now, for users with *Partner Community License* and *Customer Community License*, I could see all the records on the list view "All Contacts" of the object "Contact". All fine:

[image: Expected Behaviour for user of Customer Community Plus User Licence]

So this work only for user with  Partner Community License and Customer Community License, but NOT for Customer Community Plus User Licence

**Actual Behavior (Customer Community Plus)**

But when we login as User with License "Community Plus" we can only see a few records. Users with this license should see exactly the same contacts as users having one of the other two license types - as shown above. But unfortunately there are only shown a few contacts:

[image: Behaviour for user of Customer Community Plus User Licence in reality]
Behaviour for user with Customer Community Plus User Licence in reality

**Sharing Settings**

Now when I put Contact instead of "Controlled by Parent" to "Public Read/Write" it works for and the both users behave the same. But on "Controlled by Parent" (which I need!!) they behave differently. How can I make them behave exactly the same without putting the contact sharing to Read/Write

[image]

**Question**

How to make the Customer Plus Community Users to show exactly the same Contacts as the Customer Community while keeping the OWD as "Controlled by Parent"?

Comment: Is that real customer data in your screenshot?

Comment: No. The data is not real customer data

Comment: That's a strange one - are all accounts visible to the Customer Community Plus user?  Do you have a Sharing Set in the community?  Have you opened a case with Salesforce support?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Enabling this option 
"Allow community users to see contacts that have not been enabled for communities"
in the community setting got all contacts back!

Kindly check and let know